# How to find a file NOT containing a string in SublimeText3 or Atom

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I am trying to find files that don't contain `string` in the project finder of sublime.

I tried: `^((?!string))*$` but it returns all files that include the string. Any way to get this to work?

## My use case

I have a bunch of svg files (>400) and and they should all have a class called `icons-background` in them somewhere. Now I just want to find the svg files that don't have that class and fix them.

#### should match

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path fill="#20262d" d="M23.8 0c3.5 6.4 4.2 16-9.8"></path>
</svg>
```

#### shouldn't match

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path fill="#20262d" class="icons-background" d="M23.8 0c3.5 6.4 4.2 16-9.8"></path>
</svg>
```

#### What I get currently

[image]

#### Work around

What I ended up using is a bash command:

```
find .  -type f -wholename "*/svg/*.svg" -not -path "*/node_modules/*" -exec grep -L -H 'icons-background' '{}' ';'
```

I keep this question open however in case someone finds a solution for one of those editors.

Comment: Do you want to find the word `string` in isolation?

Comment: no I want any file that has no occurrences at all of `string`

Comment: No I mean do you want to exclude things like `stringtest`?

Comment: nope. I am looking for a CSS class that would never be there in another combination so let's keep it simple

Comment: I gave you an answer below, but for future reference you should give us many clear examples of what matches and what does not match.

Comment: You still did not give us examples of what to match.  This is a bad question.

Comment: I don't understand mate. Match all files that do not contain `string` anywhere in them. In my use case example `string` is `icons-background` if you are looking for a specific word.

Comment: Try my updated answer.  If you are looking for a specific CSS class then you should search precisely for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^((?!class="icons-background").)*$
```

You can explore this regex using the link below:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xC1yI9/2)

Comment: This seems to find lines rather than files. I am getting a lot of files that still contain `string`.

Comment: Wait a minute...are you searching file name or contents?

Comment: File contents, I edited the question to include my use case. Hope that makes it more clear. Thanks for looking into it @Tim

Comment: This still finds files with `class="icons-background"`. I assume this might be an sublime issue.

Comment: This should _not_ be matching such files.  I just tested with your sample CSS code and it appears to be working.

Comment: Did you test with Sublime3? I will add a screenshot to my question. It seems to find lines that don't include the string and not files.

Comment: I don't have Sublime unfortunately. Though the regex seems to be doing its job in the editor.  It's possible that Sublime does not support negative lookaheads.